# How to sync a downloaded zip with upstream without downloading the files again?

Tags: git, git-remote, git-fetch, upstream-branch

I downloaded llvm as a zip a while ago. It's a big repo, so I don't want to download the files again, I don't want the history either. However, I'd like to have future changes the main repo present locally with the changes I make for my own. I imagine it is possible with some rebase/merge.

I tried

```
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git
git fetch --depth 1
```

but it costs me bandwidth again:

```
Enumerating objects: 426325, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (426325/426325), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (228729/228729), done.
Receiving objects:  14% (60241/426325), 32.60 MiB | 672.00 KiB/s
```

Comment: What do you mean "it downloads the files again"? What files?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice added

Comment: "objects" are not files. These are the items that git uses to manage the history of the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A zip file of the files extracted from a commit is not a commit itself, and has no history.

A `--depth 1` clone of a repository has one commit, but has defeated Git's ability to make what Git calls *thin packs*.  There is no in-Git solution to this.

Comment: Okay I removed the depth 1 thing. I'll accept whatever saves me bandwidth.

Comment: Basically, if you're going to use Git to clone a repository, the *first* clone is painful; after that, the compression stuff usually works really well.

Comment: Since I was having build errors, clone was imminent. I did a `git checkout -b old`, `git commit`, `git checkout master` and build stuff.